# Super-slow Virtual PC on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, performance

I'm running Virtual PC on Windows 7 and the framerate (of just mouse movement) within the virtual machine is something like 1 frame per second. This makes it almost impossible to use.  Ideas?

The host is a beefy dual-nvidia Win7 RC laptop.  The guest OS is I think Windows 7 as well.

I have installed the integration components.

Comment: Virtualising is pretty heavy stuff, your system up to it?

Comment: What are the specs for the Host PC? What are the specs of the Guest OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running that video player through that seamless integration feature, disable it (Shift-Escape during startup). This will give you screen of virtual machine instead of RDP connection.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit?  Is there a way to make the virtual machine go full screen in order to give it priority and then get better performance out of it?  Thanks.

Comment: During start-up of virtual machine just press Shift-Escape in order to get virtual machine window. Once you get windows, there is option of full screen somewhere (or try AltGr+Enter).
Act of getting to virtual machine window (instead of remote desktop connection) should make video faster. I am not sure that full screen will give it any more speed.

Answer (score 1):

Install VirtualBox OSE and try to run the same VM image. If it works, then the problem isn't in the OS, but in the VirtualPC virtualisation software.

You can find VirtualBox here: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

If the problem is in VirtualPC, you can either stop using it, or contact them with the information that a certain image works in VirtualBox but not in VirtualPC. This may motivate them to fix it for you faster.